# convert mp4 to hls but with variable segments size

Tags: ffmpeg, http-live-streaming, transcoding, hls.js, aws-media-convert

I saw several examples to change mp4 container to hls using ffmpeg easily with something like this:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -profile:v baseline -level 3.0 -s 640x360 -start_number 0 -hls_time 10 -hls_list_size 0 -f hls index.m3u8
```

I observed that usually the last fragment could be really different with the others (because it is like an offset only). Then I guess that a fix segment length is not mandatory

I have been asking, is it possible to change the size of another fragments? For example, fix hls_time=10 for all the segments except for segments `(1)` or `(1, 2)` such that the length for these to be 5 instead of 10?

Is possible? with ffmpeg or any other?